# PHP: Installing PECL Extensions

Tags: php, pecl

I'm on a `Mac OS X 10.6` and If I type in the terminal:

```
Me:~ Me$ pecl install extname
```

Then I get this error:

```
-bash: pecl: command not found
```

How can I make the `pecl command` work?

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.pear.php) this should work, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you compile PHP from scratch or did you get it as a pre-made build from somewhere? Many of the builds strip out parts.

Comment: Hi @SilverbackNet , I use MAMP 1.9.4 do you think that this is the problem? :|

Comment: Ref link:
[http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion)

Answer (score 1):

hm.. mine is working:

```
sayaMac:~ ayik$ pecl channel-info
No channel specified
sayaMac:~ ayik$ whereis pecl
/usr/bin/pecl
sayaMac:~ ayik$
```

please make sure /usr/bin is in your PATH env. check with:

```
sayaMac:~ ayik$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/ayik/adb/tools
sayaMac:~ ayik$
```

Comment: Hi @chenull , thanks I don't really know what do you want but I made made this: `echo $PATH` and I get this : `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` now what?

Comment: in my 10.6 Mac, pecl is located in /usr/bin/pecl. your path is correct (/usr/bin is there). or do you need to sudo 1st? run "sudo su -" and re-run pecl install xxx